# Can I disable Command-Q on a Mac in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos, keyboard

The quickest way to drop full stacks of items in Minecraft (on a Mac) is to use Command-Q. But that keyboard shortcut is already set by Apple to quit the application. Is there a way to disable Command-Q to quit in Minecraft? I don't want to change the drop item keybind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mac likes to be annoying when it comes to game shortcuts, but you can override the Command-Q shortcut to use Minecraft's method of dropping items by using Ctrl-Command-Q. If you want to learn more about Minecraft shortcuts you can check out [this website](https://defkey.com/minecraft-java-edition-shortcuts).

Comment: To be fair, the same issue would likely occur if MC had Alt + F4 set for this keybinding on Windows. Inconsiderate third-party development != Apple being annoying with keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Fam, it's an operating system. It's not the annoying thing here. Anyway, let me go change my keybinds.

Comment: This does not work on Ventura, it just locks the screen.

Comment: ^ As mentioned, this keybind is now used by Mac for "Lock Screen".

Answer (score 3):

So, I actually just made a mod for this. It's for Fabric and it's for 1.16.4+. Here's the link: [**Ctrl Q**](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/ctrl-q).

The mod is basically remapping the default Command key for Ctrl when dropping items. I myself had this issue, and it's only recently that I learnt how to make mods so I can code it. Have fun!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The actual accepted answer doesn't seem to work for me on Ventura.

Answer (score 2):

There's actually a forge mod for Minecraft called "[Patcher](https://sk1er.club/mods/patcher)" that allows you to change the drop modifier key in controls. I changed the drop modifier key to option and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to, you can remap it globally at the system level under Preferences -> Keyboard -> Accessibility. [This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/78948/287188) has suggestions ranging from setting Cmd + Q as the shortcut for "invert colors" to "do not disturb".

Of course, this will change it for *all apps* though, and you'll still have Cmd + Option + Q for Force Quit, but that's obviously harder to accidentally do.

Answer (score 0):

There is now way that you can turn off the Mac Command-Q. So you will need to change it in Minecraft to different keys.